# Translating from dplyr to data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Is there any way I could translate this code to data.table? Im not so advanced on data.table, but it seems a lot faster, so I'm reviewing this code and wondering if it's possible to translate it. How to switch mutate(across) and then these further usage of functions to data.table and how to pipe it the same way as it is piped now.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

data %>%
  group_split(Forecaster, CountryName) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            dplyr::mutate(across(c(X2022, X2023), ~ slide_dbl(., .f = ~ if(is.na(.x[2])) {
              .x[2]
            } else if(is.na(.x[1]) & !is.na(.x[2])){
              .x[2]
            } else if((.x[1] - .x[2]) != 0) {
              .x[2]
            } else {
              NA_real_
            }, .before = 1, .complete = TRUE), .names = 'Updated_{.col}')))
```

For reproducability:

```
data <- structure(list(Forecaster = c("Moody's Analytics", "Oxford Economics", 
                                "Julius Baer", "Fitch Solutions", "SEB", "Allianz", "EIU", "FrontierView", 
                                "Euromonitor Int.", "Fitch Ratings", "Scope Ratings", "Allianz", 
                                "EIU", "Euromonitor Int.", "Fitch Ratings", "Fitch Solutions", 
                                "FrontierView", "Julius Baer", "Moody's Analytics", "Oxford Economics", 
                                "Scope Ratings", "SEB", "Allianz", "EIU", "Euromonitor Int.", 
                                "Fitch Ratings", "Fitch Solutions", "FrontierView", "Julius Baer", 
                                "Moody's Analytics", "Oxford Economics", "Scope Ratings", "SEB", 
                                "Allianz", "EIU", "Euromonitor Int.", "Fitch Ratings", "Fitch Solutions", 
                                "FrontierView", "Julius Baer", "Moody's Analytics", "Oxford Economics", 
                                "Scope Ratings", "SEB", "Allianz", "EIU", "Euromonitor Int.", 
                                "Fitch Ratings", "Fitch Solutions", "FrontierView", "Julius Baer", 
                                "Moody's Analytics", "Oxford Economics", "Scope Ratings"), 
CountryName = c("USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), 
ProductName = c("Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation"), 
X2022 = c(6.58180388987726, 
          7.39615, 5.71530516215215, 6.5, NA, 6.1, 7.2, 6.2, 7.31, 6.9, 
          NA, 6.1, 7.7, 7.49, 6.9, 6.5, 6.2, 7.01535416655227, 6.94177167480419, 
          7.40344, NA, 7.5, 6.1, 7.7, 7.49, 6.9, 6.5, 6.2, 7.01535416655227, 
          6.94177167480419, 7.40344, NA, 7.5, NA, 8.3, 7.99, 7.8313, 7.3, 
          8.4, 7.45242025035952, 7.51681072158563, 8.04052, NA, 7.5, 8.2, 
          8.1, 8.01, 7.8313, 7.7, 8.6, 7.94553624147252, 7.82785941572661, 
          8.11193, NA), 
X2023 = c(2.62716826359282, 1.73992, 2.32590118928029, 
        2.5, NA, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 4.02, 2.7, NA, 2.5, 3.7, 4.01, 2.7, 2.5, 
        3.3, 2.96909559451206, 2.70488419782626, 2.01984, NA, 4.2, 2.5, 
        3.7, 4.01, 2.7, 2.5, 3.3, 2.96909559451206, 2.70488419782626, 
        2.01984, NA, 4.2, NA, 3.7, 4.21, 3.7199, 3.5, 4.9, 3.02315479834998, 
        3.10232274684858, 3.17401, NA, 4.2, 3.2, 3.8, 4, 3.7199, 3.7, 
        5.7, 3.48906158848119, 3.36435085973137, 3.27724, NA), 
file_month = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
   6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
   8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
   9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-54L))
```

Comment: can you explain in words what you want the code to do? I am not familiar with slider so I can't be sure by reading that I understand it. it looks like you want frollapply.

Comment: This question is too vague and does not pose SPECIFIC coding questions, but rather "please do some coding for me". I am voting to close it down. That said, check the `dtplyr` package, which provides a `dplyr` front-end for data.table. It can even translate dplyr code for you, up to some point.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution with  `.SDcols` and `frollapply` :

- `.before = 1` with `slider` is equivalent to a `left` rolling window on 2 values with `frollapply`
- `.complete = T` is the default behaviour of `frollapply`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

cols <- c("X2022", "X2023")

f <- function(y){
  if(is.na(y[2])) {
    y[2]
  } else if(is.na(y[1]) & !is.na(y[2])){
    y[2]
  } else if((y[1] - y[2]) != 0) {
    y[2]
  } else {
    NA_real_
  }}

data[,paste0("Updated_",cols ):= frollapply(.SD,2,align='left',FUN = f)
     ,by=.(Forecaster, CountryName),.SDcols=cols] %>% 
   .[order(Forecaster,CountryName)]

           Forecaster CountryName ProductName    X2022    X2023 file_month Updated_X2022 Updated_X2023
               <char>      <char>      <char>    <num>    <num>      <int>         <num>         <num>
 1:           Allianz         USA   Inflation 6.100000 2.500000          5            NA            NA
 2:           Allianz         USA   Inflation 6.100000 2.500000          6            NA            NA
 3:           Allianz         USA   Inflation 6.100000 2.500000          7            NA            NA
 4:           Allianz         USA   Inflation       NA       NA          8      8.200000      3.200000
 5:           Allianz         USA   Inflation 8.200000 3.200000          9            NA            NA
 6:               EIU         USA   Inflation 7.200000 2.800000          5      7.700000      3.700000
 7:               EIU         USA   Inflation 7.700000 3.700000          6            NA            NA
 8:               EIU         USA   Inflation 7.700000 3.700000          7      8.300000            NA
 9:               EIU         USA   Inflation 8.300000 3.700000          8      8.100000      3.800000
10:               EIU         USA   Inflation 8.100000 3.800000          9            NA            NA
11:  Euromonitor Int.         USA   Inflation 7.310000 4.020000          5      7.490000      4.010000
```

Comment: you could use keyby= instead order
(however in my case (spanish) there is a different collation between dplyr::group_split and data.table leyby ‍♂️)

Comment: AFAIR frollapply allows vectorized input so no need for lapply. If it doesn't now, then soon it will.

Answer (score 1):

```
setDT(data)
data[, c("Updated_X2022", "Updated_X2023") := lapply(.SD, function(x){
  ifelse(
    seq_along(x)==1, NA_real_,             # because .complete = TRUE
    ifelse(is.na(x), x, ifelse(is.na(shift(x)) & !is.na(x), x ,
  ifelse(shift(x) - x != 0, x , NA_real_))))
}) , keyby=.(Forecaster, CountryName), .SDcols =c("X2022", "X2023") ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If speeding up is what you are looking for, you might not need to switch to `data.table`. You can do a lot to clean up and optimize the code you already are using. For example, there is no need to split the dataframe and then map. You can just use `group_by`. Also, you don't need to do a sliding widow of size 2. You can just use `lag` to look behind. Lastly, you can consolidate a lot of your `if` `else` logic into one evaluation using `case_when`. Implementing all of these changes significantly increases the speed of your code (see the benchmarks at the bottom). I'm not saying that this solution is faster than the `data.table` solutions, but I find that there is always a balance between development time (i.e., time it will take you to effectively learn `data.table`) and computation time.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

#your method
example <- data %>%
  group_split(Forecaster, CountryName) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            dplyr::mutate(across(c(X2022, X2023), ~ slide_dbl(., .f = ~ if(is.na(.x[2])) {
              .x[2]
            } else if(is.na(.x[1]) & !is.na(.x[2])){
              .x[2]
            } else if((.x[1] - .x[2]) != 0) {
              .x[2]
            } else {
              NA_real_
            }, .before = 1, .complete = TRUE), .names = 'Updated_{.col}')))

#simplified and cleaned up tidyverse method
simplified <- data |>
  group_by(Forecaster, CountryName) |>
  mutate(across(c(X2022, X2023),
                ~case_when(
                  row_number() == 1 ~ NA_real_,
                  is.na(.) ~ .,
                  is.na(lag(.)) & !is.na(.) ~ .,
                  lag(.) - . != 0 ~ .,
                  TRUE ~ NA_real_
                ),
                .names = 'Updated_{.col}')) |>
  ungroup()|>
  arrange(Forecaster, CountryName)


#both methods produce the same results
all_equal(example, simplified)
#> [1] TRUE


#define your method for benchmark
old_method <- function(){
  data %>%
  group_split(Forecaster, CountryName) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            dplyr::mutate(across(c(X2022, X2023), ~ slide_dbl(., .f = ~ if(is.na(.x[2])) {
              .x[2]
            } else if(is.na(.x[1]) & !is.na(.x[2])){
              .x[2]
            } else if((.x[1] - .x[2]) != 0) {
              .x[2]
            } else {
              NA_real_
            }, .before = 1, .complete = TRUE), .names = 'Updated_{.col}')))
}

#define new method for benchmark
new_method <- function(){
  data |>
  group_by(Forecaster, CountryName) |>
  mutate(across(c(X2022, X2023),
                ~case_when(
                  row_number() == 1 ~ NA_real_,
                  is.na(.) ~ .,
                  is.na(lag(.)) & !is.na(.) ~ .,
                  lag(.) - . != 0 ~ .,
                  TRUE ~ NA_real_
                ),
                .names = 'Updated_{.col}')) |>
  ungroup()|>
  arrange(Forecaster, CountryName)
}


#evaluate computation time
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  old = old_method(),
  new = new_method()
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq     max neval cld
#>   old 37.0722 40.64855 42.94233 42.2888 44.72170 59.2786   100   b
#>   new 10.1105 10.83675 11.81004 11.3613 12.22565 20.5520   100  a
```